# Flutter number keyboard doesn't have done button on IOS device

Tags: ios, keyboard, flutter

I'm using TextInputType.number in my TextField. But there is not any done or next button inside keyboard on IOS device.TextInputAction.done isn’t working on number keyboard. What should I do for that ?

My Flutter version is  `v0.7.3`